# Disable mouse click event while executing jquery function

Tags: jquery

I want to do an horizontal accordion at on focus and focusout a textfield. To implement this I am using the jQuery animation. It is working fine but if the textfield loses the focus before completing the animation, the alignment becomes incorrect. So I would like to block the mouse click event until completion of jQuery function/execution.

For your reference this is my code:

```
$(".container-inline input[type=text]").focusin(function() {    
    $("#page-wrap").width("720px");
    $("#my_search").width("171px"); 
    $("#myDiv").animate( { width: "150px" },{queue: false, duration: 1000});
});

$(".container-inline input[type=text]").focusout(function(){
    $("#page-wrap").width("720px");
    $("#my_search").width("171px");
    $("#myDiv").width("88px");
});
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Look into [jQuery BolckUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)

Comment: Try to use a click event handler and use a combinaison of preventDefault, stopPropagation and stopEvent. (maybe the two first ones will work)

Comment: I think , you are looking at the problem in the wrong direction. You cant/shouldnt block the mouse click event. Instead focus on the alignment problem.

Comment: First of all thanks for yours response. I fixed the alignment issue using the jQuery stop() function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) in jQuery which can be used to check whether the animations queued have been done or not. It can used like the following the way

```
$("div").promise().done(function() {
  alert("Finished!");
});
```

Otherwise i would suggest you to have a flag variable to check whether the animation is completed or not. and you can do the focus out to drop if the animation is not over by checking the flag variable. like the following way

```
var animationOver = false;
$(".container-inline input[type=text]").focusin(function() {    
    $("#page-wrap").width("720px");
    $("#my_search").width("171px"); 
    $("#myDiv").animate( { width: "150px" },{queue: false, duration: 1000});
    animationOver = true;
});

$(".container-inline input[type=text]").focusout(function(){
    if (!animationOver)
      return false;
    $("#page-wrap").width("720px");
    $("#my_search").width("171px");
    $("#myDiv").width("88px");
    animationOver = false;
});
```

as iamkhush said, there is nothing we can get helped by blocking mouse click :(

Comment: First of all thanks for yours response. I fixed the alignment issue using the jQuery stop() function.

Comment: but be aware that stop() will stop the animation and not get back the element to its original position, you must handle this case if some part of the animation got completed.